# Bootcamp assistant hides partitions to windows?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, ntfs

macBook pro mid 2014, High Sierra, Windows 10, Ubuntu

I used Bootcamp assistant to resize one unique partition to make space for  Windows NTFS partition, then I used Windows disk manager to resize the NTFS partition and made place beyond for NTFS shared partition, linux partition, etc. All went OK and all systems had read/write access to shared NTFS

Later I reused Bootcamp to reinstall Windows on its specific NTFS partition (in this case Bootcamp does not pass through resize step). Mac and linux still have access to NTFS share, but not Windows. Moreover windows Disk Manager does not shows the remaining partitions (share, linux, etc) beyond its install partition, instead it shows one unique big unallocated partition.

As if Bootcamp install prevents Windows to correctly see disk space beyond its installation partition. Is there a way to repair this ? Disk utility does not see any problem on any partitions.

Comment: It would appear you installed Windows 10 to use the BIOS boot method.    For your model Mac, Windows 10 should be installed to use the EFi boot method. In the past, using the Windows 10 partitioning tools would lead to failure. You seemed to have succeeded. I assume this has occurred because you are using APFS, but I have no proof of this.

Comment: @DavidAnderson your are right, it is AFPS and windows mode is bios as winload.exe appears in bcdedit, though marked "inherited" in system information panel. This is strange because after previous bootcamp install under High Sierra AFPS, it was marked "uefi" in information panel. Despite the usb key created by bootcamp contains an EFI folder it has a fdisk partition scheme, so it confirms that it installs in bios mode, right? How could I prevent Bootcamp to create a fdisk key ?

Comment: The fact that windows disk manager only see the first 4 GUID partitions as allocated is also consistent with bios boot, as fdisk disks can contain only 4 primary partitions, so it would only allow to extend the last one and not create new primary partitions.

Comment: You should change the MBR partition table back to a fully protected MBR. Also, you should boot the Microsoft installer flash drive to command prompt and change the boot method back to EFI.  Do you need help to do this?

Comment: @DavidAnderson for the first part I guess I should re-use gdisk to (re-)create an empty protective MBR on the SSD (it has switched back to hybrid) ? For the second part I have no idea. Notice that the flash drive only boots with EFI enabled in Virtualbox. Your help is welcome.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea for part 1. For part 2, [see my accepted answer to the question: Recover Bootcamp EFI Folder/fix boot entries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308729/recover-bootcamp-efi-folder-fix-boot-entries/308735#308735)