# Need help making Windows bootable after installing Linux

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup, unix

I used [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed) questions's answer to install Linux(I installed Mint, however, not Ubuntu) and followed along.

I do believe I didn't follow the answer properly, as I still have a placeholder partition unused, but Linux installed and works perfectly. I did have to use the `diskutil resizevolume disk0s2 140G 3 jhfs+ part1 800M jhfs+ part2 200M jhfs+ part3 200` command differently as I am on High Sierra, and I have APFS containers. I gave 4GB for Linux Swap

Linux Mint works perfectly, but when trying to boot into Windows via the option boot menu(on startup), the built-in boot manager freezes. If Windows is set to the default startup drive, I get a blank screen.

The Bootcamp partition has next to no important information, I can format/reinstall it if necessary.

The following is my `diskutil list` output. BaseQi is a exFAT 64GB SD Card.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         120.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         3.9 GB     disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         64.1 GB    disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS part3                   200.0 MB   disk0s5
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                61.8 GB    disk0s6
   7:                        EFI NO NAME                 500.2 MB   disk0s7

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +120.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume macOS                   15.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 65.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *64.0 GB    disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS BaseQi                  64.0 GB    disk2s1
```

Below is the output for `diskutil info disk0s6`

```
    Device Identifier:        disk0s6
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0s6
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk0

   Volume Name:              BOOTCAMP
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/BOOTCAMP

   Partition Type:           Microsoft Basic Data
   File System Personality:  NTFS
   Type (Bundle):            ntfs
   Name (User Visible):      Windows NT File System (NTFS)

   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified
   Volume UUID:              163F7FD4-C9A1-4E82-BA76-8FDA822A9A52
   Disk / Partition UUID:    0721D35A-134A-4C99-B221-43CDD77F19B4
   Partition Offset:         189210296320 Bytes (369551360 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                61.8 GB (61789437952 Bytes) (exactly 120682496 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       61.8 GB (61789433856 Bytes) (exactly 120682488 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:        14.8 GB (14825717760 Bytes) (exactly 28956480 512-Byte-Units) (24.0%)
   Volume Free Space:        47.0 GB (46963716096 Bytes) (exactly 91726008 512-Byte-Units) (76.0%)
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Yes

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo reboot disk0s6`, or try rebooting into the recovery partition and running that command from there

Comment: Doesn't seem to work; Just get a a blank screen

Comment: I'm guessing that this only happens while trying to boot up from the windows drive?

Comment: Could you please post what shows up when you type `diskutil info disk0s6`

Comment: updated original post

Comment: Yes, it only happens for the Windows drive; Linux and macOS work fine

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? Also, It appears you incorrectly chose `disk0s7` for the EFI partition labeled `NO NAME`. The correct choice should have been `disk0s5`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson 13" 2014. Oh, maybe it's that, I do think I did something wrong with partitioning. I believe this might be either a EFI related thing, or Windows unable to boot on a GPT disk or something like that. Again, I did get Linux and macOS to work together, it's just that Windows won't boot. Also, I don't think this is wrong? In the linked answer, 500MB partition is for the EFI, the 200MB is a placeholder, and I did use the 500MB partition for EFI. The other 200MB placeholder partition was left unused though; my drive order was different or something during the Linux install process

Comment: @DavidAnderson Do you think this is fixable, or should I nuke my drive and retry?

Comment: I'm not sure this is fixable, but from my experience bootcamp looks right. So maybe try nuking it and starting again?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j1Yggrbb this is the output from the command used to make the needed partitions for Linux. I believe due to how APFS sees things, it makes the partitions in a different way.

Comment: If this doesn't work, I'll try with macOS Sierra

Comment: Same result, with High Sierra, attempting to boot Windows freezes the built in boot menu, and blank screen when booting Windows by default.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Okay I think the actual issue is my absence of a Microsoft Reserved partition

Comment: Have you tried repairing from a windows boot media (thumb drive, dvd)?

Comment: Best guess: Installing Mint overwrote the `/EFI/BOOT/Bootx64.efi` file in `disk0s1`. You could try coping `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` to  `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`. Otherwise, your question might be a duplicate of [Recover Bootcamp EFI Folder/fix boot entries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308729/recover-bootcamp-efi-folder-fix-boot-entries). The accepted answer is basically is what @Sam suggested.

Comment: If my best guess is the problem, then it will not be your fault. The link in your question refers to a procedure which worked with Ubuntu 16. When Mint installs, the `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` file created by Microsoft is overwritten. This is also true if you install Ubuntu 18, which is the current version.

Comment: @PiAhoy: You used the command `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 140G 3 jhfs+ part1 4G jhfs+ part2 200M jhfs+ part3 200M`. I believe the correct usage is `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 140G 3 jhfs+ part1 4G jhfs+ part2 200M jhfs+ part3 0`. In other words, you should let the command determine the exact size of the last partition. Although, in your case, you are going to delete the partitions and recreate new ones, so the exact sizes probably are not that important.