# Bootcamp just goes to black screen after trying to install linux

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition

The other day I installed linux to a partition on my 2019 macbook pro. It didn’t work the way I thought it would so I just deleted the partition that had linux. Now when I try to boot into windows with bootcamp it just goes to a black screen and nothing happens. If anyone has an idea of how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you still boot macOS?

Comment: Yes, and I can see the bootcamp partition with all the windows files.

Comment: It sounds like there might be some missing EFI files.

Comment: I figured that. I read somewhere that linux and windows use similar or the same efi files so linux messed up windows files. Do you know how I would be able to fix this?

Comment: Try this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308729/recover-bootcamp-efi-folder-fix-boot-entries)

Comment: I actually did but when I tried the list volumes command all I saw was the usb drive.

Comment: Have you tried First Aid?

Comment: No, what is that?

Comment: Never mind, that doesn’t follow the steps of the question sand it only fixes macOS drives.

Comment: Your best choice is to back up personal files via macOS. Just copy and paste from Finder. Then, remove the Boot Camp partition and redo it from Boot Camp Assistant. Make sure you also remove using Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that. I can just copy and paste the windows files? I’m not sure if you can add files to boot camp from Mac.

Comment: You can’t. You can use a flash drive. Yes just copy from Finder.

Comment: Ok but once I install windows again how do I put the files back?

Comment: You can put the files on an ExFat formatted flash drive or in iCloud, OneDrive and boot Windows and copy them.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.Thanks for all of your help.